# Total number of orthonomal list for a linearly independent set of $m$ vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given a linearly independent list of $m$  vectors (none of them are orthogonal to each other), if we apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to each of the $m!$ orderings then will each time I will get a different orthonomal list i.e total $m!$ orthonormal lists, or some of them will be same ?

Comment: If your vectors are already orthonormed, they won't be modified. When you say lists are equal, you mean element-wise or the set they represent are the same?

Comment: @xavierm02: Suppose $\{v_1,v_2\}$ was the original list. Then $\{e_1=\frac{v_1}{||v_1||},\frac{v_2 - <v_2,e_1>e_1}{||v_2 - <v_2,e_1>e_1||}\}$ and $\{e_2=\frac{v_2}{||v_2||},\frac{v_1 - <v_1,e_2>e_2}{||v_1 - <v_1,e_2>e_2||}\}$ are two different lists. Right ?

Comment: @user103623 I believe xaviermo's question (and mine) is whether the order of your list matters. Take the case where we start with the standard basis vectors. No matter how we order them, GS always yields the standard basis vectors as a set (though in different order). Does this count as 1, or as $m!$ ways?

Answer (score 0):

They will indeed all be different. For  suppose that two orderings $(v_{i_1},v_{i_2}, \ldots ,v_{i_m})$ and $(v_{j_1},v_{j_2}, \ldots ,v_{j_m})$ give the same basis.

Then the first vector is $\frac{v_{i_1}}{||v_{i_1}||}=\frac{v_{j_1}}{||v_{j_1}||}$. If $i_1\neq j_1$,
the two vectors $v_{i_1}$ and $v_{j_1}$ would be independent, and this equality would be impossible.
So we mut have $i_1=j_1$.

By induction, one sees then that $i_k=j_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: But why must we have the first vector of each set be the same? Unless by list, you are interpreting it as an ordered set. (I've made a comment on the question to reflect this.)

Comment: Put another way, you have not used the condition that the vectors are not mutually perpendicular. It is clear that no matter how we order the standard vectors, Gram-Schmidt would always yield the standard vectors. As such, there is 1 set (though $m!$ ordered variations).